# V6.0- Incoming Shipment state suddenly change from available to done

Tags: python, svn, odoo

Hi friends can you please help me on this problem? or any of you have met this problem and have solved it?

Now i'm using openerp version 6.0 to develop a project. But i found a strange issue.
My incoming state with the reference no "***TempXXXXX***" suddenly changed from **Available** to **"DONE"** and this issue happened just on 2 record of my incoming shipment.

When i was go to check it, i found that the incoming was auto generate from PO and have revised 1 time (i have created function of revised the PO), so i assumed the scenario for this issue is as the following:

1. The user created a PO and added an item to the PO.
2. The user has approved the PO and the Incoming Shipment has been generated with "Available" state.
3. The another user (lets call purchaser) found out that the item is wrong and revised the PO.
4. The purchaser removed the previous item and inserted the new one.
5. The PO has been approved once again but the state of the Incoming Shipment changed to "Done".

Note:

1. This is only an assumed scenario as this issue happened when the PO has been revised and the "Notes" written by the user (purchaser) stated that they revised the item code (means that they changed the item and added another new one).
2. I have try to duplicate this record and try it like the scenario that i have assumed, but i wasn't occur.

Thanks Before.